# text in cell have ',' uploading .csv is not working

Tags: mysql, csv

The .csv file i am using to upload data has ',' in the cell. How can i ignore the ',' in cells so the data in that cell goes in a single field of my database.

cell data="There is lead-based paint peeling from the walls, and mold growing on the walls. Summarize the health hazards associated with lead and mold, and describe what may be done to control these two public health problems. Please be sure to support your position with evidence from the literature"

This text should go in one field but because there is a ',' in the text it is going in 2 fields.

Does anyone know a fix for this.

Thanks

PHP code

```
$fieldseparator = ",";
$lineseparator = "\n";

$csvfile = "SampleDataTab.txt";
//echo $csvfile;
/********************************/
/* Would you like to add an ampty field at the beginning of these records?
/* This is useful if you have a table with the first field being an auto_increment integer
/* and the csv file does not have such as empty field before the records.
/* Set 1 for yes and 0 for no. ATTENTION: don't set to 1 if you are not sure.
/* This can dump data in the wrong fields if this extra field does not exist in the table
/********************************/
$addauto = 0;
/********************************/
/* Would you like to save the mysql queries in a file? If yes set $save to 1.
/* Permission on the file should be set to 777. Either upload a sample file through ftp and
/* change the permissions, or execute at the prompt: touch output.sql && chmod 777 output.sql
/********************************/
$save = 1;
$outputfile = "output.sql";
/********************************/
echo $csvfile;

if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
    echo "File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.\n";
    exit;
}

$file = fopen($csvfile,"r");

if(!$file) {
    echo "Error opening data file.\n";
    exit;
}

$size = filesize($csvfile);

if(!$size) {
    echo "File is empty.\n";
    exit;
}

$csvcontent = fread($file,$size);

fclose($file);

$con = mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());
//'/\s/',
$records=0;
$lines = 0;
$queries = "";
$query="";
$linearray = array();
//array preg_split ( string $pattern , string $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int $flags = 0 ]] )
foreach(preg_split('/\n/',$csvcontent) as $line) {
echo"<BR>". $line."<BR>";
    $lines++;

    $line = trim($line," \t");

    $line = str_replace("\r","",$line);

    /************************************
    This line escapes the special character. remove it if entries are already escaped in the csv file
    ************************************/
    if($lines==1)
    $line = str_replace("`","\'",$line);
else
    $line = str_replace("'","\'",$line);
    /*************************************/

    $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);


    $stat=  mysql_query("select status_id from status where status='$linearray[3]'");
     $status=mysql_fetch_row($stat);


    $wri=  mysql_query("select user_id from writer where name='$linearray[4]'");
     $writer=mysql_fetch_row($wri);


    $due= date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($linearray[5]));
    $ord_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($linearray[6]));

    if($writer[0]==null)
    echo "Please insert writer in database. Cannot add record";
    else
    {
    echo "<BR> category: ".$linearray[13]."<BR>";
if($lines!=1)
{
        $query = "insert into `$databasetable` (website,order_id,status,writer_id,due_date,order_recieve_date,no_of_pages,customer_name,topic,details,category,education_level,format,citation_style,email,alt_email) values('$linearray[0]','$linearray[1]',$status[0],$writer[0],'$due','$ord_date',$linearray[8],'$linearray[10]','$linearray[11]','$linearray[12]','$linearray[13]','$linearray[14]','$linearray[17]','$linearray[18]','$linearray[19]','$linearray[20]');";

    $queries .= $query . "\n";}

echo $query."<BR>";
$records+=  mysql_query($query);

echo $records;

}
}

mysql_close($con);

if($save) {

    if(!is_writable($outputfile)) {
        echo "File is not writable, check permissions.\n";
    }

    else {
        $file2 = fopen($outputfile,"w");

        if(!$file2) {
            echo "Error writing to the output file.\n";
        }
        else {
            fwrite($file2,$queries);
            fclose($file2);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you importing the data into MySql, through 'LOAD DATA INFILE ...'?

Comment: no, I have to insert get records from .csv file and insert them in database through php

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax, add `ENCLOSED BY '"'` to your query.

Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: I can't use this because I have to get records from .csv file and insert them in database using PHP

Comment: @shazia If you are using php to insert the records, you should have already surrounded the cell data with quotes. the comma in the cell data will not split the fields. i am very surprised you are able to insert data without MySql errors. Can you please update your question with the php code?

Comment: I have uploaded the code....I am not writing the excel files...so i have no control over what data exists in the cells. I need to get the data from the cells to appropriate fields in db. I hope this clarifies things a bit

Comment: @shazia What field/`$linearray` is the sample data? try surrounding your inputs with `mysql_real_escape_string()`